# Access attributes from an associated model rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I want to display the ingredients for each recipe on the recipe show view, the ingredients are in a separate model called ingredients but have a belongs_to relationship with the recipe model

So when i call user name for example i use

```
@recipe.user.name
```

This is because the attributes are within the recipe model, I have a method in the recipe helper like so

```
  def ingredient_names(ingredients)
  if ingredients
  ingredient_array = ingredients.map {|ing| ing.ingredient_name}
  ingredient_array.join("\n")
  end
  end
```

So i thought i could call

```
@recipe.ingredient_names
```

but i get an undefined method error..

Then i thought i had to pass the params ingredient_name (name of the column)

```
@recipe.ingredient_names(:ingredient_name)
```

but still get undefined method error

and when i do

```
<%= @recipe.ingredients(:ingredient_name) %>
```

i get this as the output

```
[#<Ingredient id: 71, ingredient_name: "Ingredient 1", recipe_id: 56, created_at: "2012-11-29 19:29:25", updated_at: "2012-12-02 16:29:58">, #<Ingredient id: 76, ingredient_name: "ingredient 2", recipe_id: 56, created_at: "2012-12-02 16:29:59", updated_at: "2012-12-02 16:29:59">, #<Ingredient id: 77, ingredient_name: "ingredient 3", recipe_id: 56, created_at: "2012-12-02 16:29:59", updated_at: "2012-12-02 16:29:59">]
```

so how do i call the attributes for another model when i have the relationship belongs_to and has_many. Simple question i guess but cant figure it out

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution, i needed to access the method first

```
<%= ingredient_names @recipe.ingredients(:ingredient_name)
```